# Как делать, чтобы запомнил выбор?

Tags: java, android

Создаю игру Крестик VS Нолик, есть 4 activity... 1)Где есть кнопки new game и exit... 2) 1 игрок или 2 игрока... 3) играть крестиком или ноликом и 4) сама игра...
на первом activity все ясно, нажимаю новая игра и заходит на 2ой activity... Но вот вопрос..... как делать, чтоб он запомнил какие кнопки нажали, всмысле когда я нажимаю на 1 игрок и откроется activity, где нужно выбрать чем играть крестиком или ноликом, и потом начнется игра, но как делать, чтоб он знал какие кнопки были нажаты, думаю понятно объясняю)) сори просто я еще новичок, но прошу помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте переменные `playersNum` и `sign` и записывайте в них значения в зависимости о того какие кнопки нажаты. Например если выбрано 2 игрока и крестик, то `playersNum` присваивается значение 0, а `sign` присваеватся значение 1.

Comment: Вот именно как сказать что было выбрано 2 игрока и крестик, вот это и мне интересует, они на разных activity

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan используйте глобальные переменные

Comment: Переменные не помогут, тут должен быть метод, чтоб в 4ой activity сказать, что если нажато 2 игрока из 2ого activity и выбрано крестик из 3ого activity, то начинай игру таким способом

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan сделайте в activity2 и activity3 геттер и с помощью него получайте переменные в activity4